# How to show the detail in a Master-Detail form with Datatables Jquery

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, datatables

I am designing a system with Net Core 5 MVC, I have to show a Master-Detail, I already have the Master view that contains a Datatable, I would like that when clicking on the ID field (according to the image), the view with the detail would be displayed , but I don't know how to call the Detail view.

[Header image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I7Sr.png)

The code I have in the master is the following (Controller, JS, View):

This's the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoadDataGrid()
{
    var draw = Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();
    var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
    var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();
    var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault() + "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
    var sortColumnDir = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();
    var searchValue = Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault().ToUpper();

    pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
    skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
    recordsTotal = 0;

    List<VDiagramaMasterModel> ListVDiagramaMasterModel = Singleton.Instance.EntityManager.GetEntities<VDiagramaMasterModel>();

    ListVDiagramaMasterModel = (from d in ListVDiagramaMasterModel select d).ToList();

    /* Si tenemos una cadena de busqueda */
    if (searchValue != "")
    {
        ListVDiagramaMasterModel = ListVDiagramaMasterModel.Where(x => x.DiagramaId.ToString().Contains(searchValue) ||
            x.FechaElaboracion.ToString().Contains(searchValue) ||
            x.DiagramaNumber.ToUpper().ToString().Contains(searchValue) ||
            x.DiagramaName.ToUpper().ToString().Contains(searchValue) ||
            x.StatusProcesoName.ToUpper().ToString().Contains(searchValue)).ToList();
    }

    recordsTotal = ListVDiagramaMasterModel.Count;

    /* Reordenar segun lo solicitado en el Grid */
    switch (sortColumn)
    {
        case "diagramaId":
            if (sortColumnDir == "asc")
                ListVDiagramaMasterModel = ListVDiagramaMasterModel.OrderBy(x => x.DiagramaId).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            else
                ListVDiagramaMasterModel = ListVDiagramaMasterModel.OrderByDescending(x => x.DiagramaId).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return Json(new { draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal, data = ListVDiagramaMasterModel });
}
```

The Javascript File where I load the Master Datatable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        filter: true,                               // Filtrado de datos
        info: true,                                 // Resultado de busquedas
        processing: true,                           // Muestra/Oculta la leyenda procesando
        scrollX: true,                              // Scroll Horizontal
        select: true,                               // Permite seleccionar el renglon
        ordering: true,                             // Activa el ordenamiento
        autoWidth: false,                           // Apaga el ancho automatico

        scroller: { "loadingIndicator": true },     // Complemento de representación virtual para DataTables para mostrar muchos datos en la pantalla muy rápidamente.
        serverSide: true,                           // Habilitar procesamiento del lado del servidor
        deferRender: true,                          // Habilitar renderizado diferido para cargar con AJAX                

        responsivePriority: 1,
        data: null,

        ajax: {
            url: "/DiagramaMaster/LoadDataGrid/",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
        },

        columns: [                                // Definicion de columnas, ID's
            {
                data: "diagramaId", name: "diagramaId",
                render: function (data) {
                    /* return "<a href='/DiagramaMaster/Details/" + data + "'>" + ("00000" + data).slice(-5) + "</a>"; */
                    return "<a href='/DiagramaDetail/Details/" + data + "'>" + ("00000" + data).slice(-5) + "</a>";
                    /*return "<a href ='#WinModal' data-id='" + data + "' data-bs-toggle='modal' class='btnGrdDetails'>" + ("0000" + data).slice(-4) + "</a>";*/

                }
            },
            {
                data: "tipoProcesoId", name: "tipoProcesoId",
                render: function (data) {
                    return ("00" + data).slice(-2);
                }
            },
            { data: "tipoProcesoName", name: "tipoProcesoName"},
            {
                data: "fechaElaboracion", name: "fechaElaboracion",
                render: function (value) {
                    var dt = new Date(value).toLocaleDateString('es-MX', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' });
                    return dt;                }
            },
            { data: "diagramaNumber", name: "diagramaNumber"},
            { data: "diagramaName", name: "diagramaName"},
            { data: "diagramaDescripcion", name: "diagramaDescripcion"},
            { data: "diagramaNotas", name: "diagramaNotas" },
            {
                data: "totalTelaKilos", name: "totalTelaKilos",
                render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 3, '')
            },
            {
                data: "incluirCuellos", name: "incluirCuellos",
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (data == true) { return '<input type="checkbox" checked disabled>'; }
                    else { return '<input type="checkbox" readonly>'; }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            {
                data: "incluirEstampe", name: "incluirEstampe",
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (data == true) { return '<input type="checkbox" checked disabled readonly>'; }
                    else { return '<input type="checkbox" readonly>'; }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            { data: "statusProcesoId", name: "statusProcesoId" },
            { data: "statusProcesoName", name: "statusProcesoName" },
            { data: "referenciaId", name: "referenciaId"},

            {
                data: "actionBar", name: "actionBar", title: "Acción", width: "100px", sortable: false,
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return "<button href='#WinModal' id='btnDetails' data-id='" + full.diagramaId + "' data-bs-toggle='modal' type='button' class='btnDetails btn btn-primary btn-sm' title='Ver'><i class='fa-solid fa-file-lines'></i></button> " +
                        "<button href='#WinModal' id='btnEdit' data-id='" + full.diagramaId + "' data-bs-toggle='modal' type='button' class='btnEdit btn btn-primary btn-sm' title='Editar'><i class='fa-solid fa-pencil'></i></button> " +
                        "<button href='#WinModal' id='btnDelete' data-id='" + full.diagramaId + "' data-bs-toggle='modal' type='button' class='btnDelete btn btn-danger btn-sm' title='Eliminar'><i class='fa-solid fa-trash'></i></button> ";
                }
            },
        ],

        order: [[0, 'asc']],
        // 0:diagramaId, 1:tipoProcesoId, 2:tipoProcesoName, 3:fechaElaboracion, 4:diagramaNumber, 5:diagramaName
        // 6:diagramaDescripcion, 7:diagramaNotas, 8:totalTelaKilos, 9:incluirCuellos, 10:incluirEstampe, 
        // 11: statusProcesoId, 12:statusProcesoName, 13:referenciaId, 14:actionBar
        columnDefs: [
            { visible: false, targets: [1, 6, 7, 11] },
            { searchable: false, targets: [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] },
            { sortable: false, targets: [1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14] },
            { className: "dt-body-center", targets: [0, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14] },
            { className: "dt-body-right", targets: [8] },
            { "width": "20px", "targets": [0] },
            { "width": "25px", "targets": [3, 9, 10] },
            { "width": "30px", "targets": [2, 13] },
            { "width": "70px", "targets": [8, 12] },
            { "width": "80px", "targets": [4] },
            { "width": "350px", "targets": [5] },
        ],

        // Cargar el Idioma Español //
        language: {
            url: "/js/language_pack/es-ES.json"
        },
    });

    /* ******************** */
    /* Dibujar la DataTable */
    /* ******************** */
    tableBase.draw()

});     // Fin $(document).ready(function () {});
```

View to load the master

```
@* Archivo cshtml para cargar el Maestro @*
<div id="divContainer" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Listado de Diagramas</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
        <p><button href="#WinModal" id="btnNew" type="button" asp-action="Create" class="btnNew btn btn-primary btn-md" data-bs-toggle="modal" title="Nuevo Diagrama" ><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> Nuevo</button></p>
    </div>

    <span class="text-danger">@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</span>
    <div class="table table-responsive">
        <table id="tableGrid" class="display cell-border"">
            <thead style="font-size:12px; color: white; background-color: #2C3E50;">
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiagramaId)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TipoProcesoId)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TipoProcesoName)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FechaElaboracion)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiagramaNumber)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiagramaName)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiagramaDescripcion)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DiagramaNotas)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalTelaKilos)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IncluirCuellos)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IncluirEstampe)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StatusProcesoId)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StatusProcesoName)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReferenciaId)</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="font-size:12px;">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <!-- Para usar las funciones del grid -->
    <script src="/js/dtg_config/diagramamaster.js"></script>
}
```

In order not to extend too much, the Detail is set up in a similar way (View, Controller, JS), but as I mentioned, I don't know how to do it so that when the ID is clicked, it brings me the view with the Detail and puts it in a DataTable, the following code is where I put together the DT of the detail.

```
// js para configurar la DataTable del detalle
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Nombre del Modelo con el que se trabajara, se   */
    /* pasa como parametro a la accion del controlador */
    //var workingModel = { Name: "CatConsignatarioModel" };
    /* *********************************************** */

    $('#tableGrid').DataTable({
        dom: "lfrtip",                      // DOM [B]: Butons (PDF, Excel, etc.), [l]:Cantidad [f]:Filtro, [r]:Visualizacion del proceso, [t]:Tabla [i]:Informacion, [p]:Paginación
        //buttons: ["copy", "excel"],       // Botones de "copy", "excel", "pdf", "csv" y "print"
        filter: true,                       // Filtrado de datos
        info: true,                         // Resultado de busquedas
        processing: true,                   // Muestra/Oculta la leyenda procesando
        scrollX: true,                      // Scroll Horizontal
        select: true,                       // Permite seleccionar el renglon
        ordering: true,                     // Activa el ordenamiento
        autoWidth: false,                   // Apaga el ancho automatico
        responsive: true,                   // Tabla responsiva
        lengthMenu: [[50, 100, 150, -1], [50, 100, 150, "All"]],

        responsivePriority: 1,

        scroller: { "loadingIndicator": true },     // Complemento de representación virtual para DataTables para mostrar muchos datos en la pantalla muy rápidamente.
        serverSide: true,                           // Habilitar procesamiento del lado del servidor
        deferRender: true,                          // Habilitar renderizado diferido para cargar con AJAX                

        responsivePriority: 1,
        data: null,

        ajax: {
            url: "/DiagramaDetail/LoadDataGrid/", //<<- This is where I don't know how to put the DiagramId
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
        },

        columns: [                                // Definicion de columnas, ID's
            {
                data: "diagramaId", name: "diagramaId",
                render: function (data) {
                    /* return "<a href='/DiagramaMaster/Details/" + data + "'>" + ("00000" + data).slice(-5) + "</a>"; */
                    return "<a href ='#WinModal' data-id='" + data + "' data-bs-toggle='modal' class='btnGrdDetails'>" + ("0000" + data).slice(-4) + "</a>";
                }
            }
        ],

  // corte la definicion de columnas para efectos de que no se haga tan extenso
    });
    /* ******************** */
    /* Dibujar la DataTable */
    /* ******************** */
    tableBase.draw()
 });
```

Comment: You mean you want to view the details of the record when you click the diagramaId, right? So which one is your want, anchor link or bootstrap modal? You want to go to a new page to display the details or just open a modal popup to display? Besides, what's wrong with your code? The anchor link cannot get into your action? What does your backend code like?

Comment: @Rena It's correct, when I click on the link I want to show the detail in a new view, because the detail can contain up to 600 rows, it is necessary to show it in a Datatables, the problem is that I don't know how to send the DiagramId to the API which loads the Datatable correct.

Comment: Hi @Luis Gerardo,  your code here `return "<a href='/DiagramaMaster/Details/" + data + "'>" + ("00000" + data).slice(-5) + "</a>";` will generate correct href with `DiagramId ` for the link. What's the error message when you click this link? How is your `/DiagramaMaster/Details` action like? And do you mean you do not render the datatable successfully in Details.cshtml?

Comment: Hello @Rena, thanks for answering, the link is correct and when entering the Controller **/Diagramamaster/Details**, correctly load the detail View, but as the DataTable I have it configured in a JavaScript, when loaded in the Ajax part I put **URL: "/Diagramadetail/LoadDataGrid/**, and here is where I have the problem, since I do not know how to tell you that I only load the **id="n"**.
I hope I have been clear with the explanation, but I do not have very good English.